# Triangle from point given grid coordinates

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Hello fellow MathExchangers,

I am wondering how can I proceed if I am given a set of 2D points as a list of $(x_i, y_i)$ and then another point, say $(x_0,y_0)$, and I would like to find the smallest shape/curve/region with grid points at the vertices that includes it.

It is obvious that the shape will be a triangle, unless of course $(x_0,y_0)$ is a point of the list, but other than brute forcing my way I can't figure out another approach. The number of 'grid' points I'd like to use are numerous, so brute force is not a viable solution.

Also, it is *not* implied anywhere that the 'grid' points are at regular intervals (hence the quotes), and anyway I'd like to find a way to solve this for any set of $(x_i, y_i)$, regular or not. The problem of course will be solved with a computer, so I don't have anything against complex methods/algorithms since it won't be solved manually.

I will have to repeat this calculation numerous times for a given set of $(x_i, y_i)$, so I don't mind if there is some way that requires much computational resources beforehand (maybe some preparational steps) but then makes it easy(fast) to find a solution, and I will code it myself so bonus points for approaches that can be parallelized (I could try GPU processing or something if necessary)

Comment: Quick answer: Triangulate the set of points. Use some "locate point" method. There are some useful links out there.

Comment: "It is obvious that the shape will be a triangle, unless of course $(x_0,y_0)$ is a point of the list ... ." It is not obvious to me. If the shape has to have a nonzero interior area then I think you need a triangle in every case; otherwise just connect $(x_0,y_0)$ to the closest "grid" point. Also, how do you measure "smallest"--area, diameter, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do a triangulation using $n$ given vertices. But there is one which has to be singled-out :  **"Delaunay triangulation"** with many good properties.
 It is efficiently implemented (often using **convex hull algorithm** with O($n \log(n)$) complexity) in all scientific software (for example in Matlab).
Delaunay triangulation, offers the possibility to efficiently retrieve the triangle which contains $(x_0,y_0)$. Moreover, it is known to be parallelizable.